# Is there a way to see False Negative rows?

Tags: r, confusion-matrix, false-positive

I have a data frame, split into train and test data sets, run svm, predict and confusion matrix functions.

How can I see which rows are False Positive and False Negative?

```
Data_7c<- Data_7G[, c(6, 15:18)] 
split = sample.split(Data_7c$F, SplitRatio = 0.70)
train = subset(Data_7c, split == TRUE)
test = subset(Data_7c, split == FALSE)

data1 = svm(F ~., data = train, method="C-classification", kernel="radial", cost = 1, gamma=0.001, scale = FALSE)
pred1 <- predict(data1, task = bh.task,newdata = test)
head(as.data.frame(pred1))
SVMcf1 <- confusionMatrix(pred1, as.factor(test[,1]), positive = "1")
SVMcf1$table

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction    0    1
         0 2203  146
         1    3    2
```

Data `test$F[1:20]` and `pred1[1:20]`:

```
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor") 

structure(c(`2` = 1L, `3` = 1L, `8` = 1L, `19` = 1L, `22` = 1L, 
`25` = 1L, `40` = 1L, `49` = 1L, `51` = 1L, `55` = 1L, `57` = 1L, 
`60` = 1L, `62` = 1L, `63` = 1L, `67` = 2L, `72` = 1L, `75` = 1L, 
`80` = 1L, `81` = 1L, `89` = 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your data using `dput`. If `pred1` and `test[,1]` are vectors of `0` and `1` then you can use logical operators to subset your data. To get the rows that are false positives you can do `pred1 & !test[,1]`. For false negatives you would do `!pred1 & test[,1]`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, here you can find it:                                                   
dput(test$F[1:20])
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")
dput(pred1[1:20])
structure(c(`2` = 1L, `3` = 1L, `8` = 1L, `19` = 1L, `22` = 1L, 
`25` = 1L, `40` = 1L, `49` = 1L, `51` = 1L, `55` = 1L, `57` = 1L, 
`60` = 1L, `62` = 1L, `63` = 1L, `67` = 2L, `72` = 1L, `75` = 1L, 
`80` = 1L, `81` = 1L, `89` = 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical operators to determine false positive and false negatives, store them in a vector, and then subset your data.

```
# convert factor to numeric 0/1
pred1 <- as.numeric(levels(pred1))[pred1] 
test$F <- as.numeric(levels(test$F))[test$F]

false_positive <- pred1 & !test$F
false_negative <- !pred1 & test$F
```

`false_positive` and `false_negative` will be logical vectors. For example, in `false_positive` it will be `TRUE` where `pred1 == 1` and `test$F == 0` and `FALSE` otherwise.

These logical vectors can then be used to subset the rows of your `test` dataset:

```
test[false_positive,]
test[false_negative,]
```

Additionally, `sum(false_positive)` should be 3 and `sum(false_negative)` should be 146 based on the output of your confusion matrix.